# Align rotation with the snapping target users interface?

Tags: interface

Hi this is my first question in this wonderful community.
How to change the color of button when clicked in active ? It's very tough to tell when it's active or not!
THANKS

Comment: ...is it me or the question title has nothing to do with the real question?

Answer (score 1):

Its pretty straight forward in blender

**Option 1:**
Please Go to;

User preference -> Themes -> 3D view -> Object selected

You may change the color to your own choice

Don't forget to save user settings at the bottom

**Option 2**
Alternatively you may fully change the theme

User preference -> Themes - Under presets there are lots of good ones

Comment: THANK YOU FOR YOUR QUICK RESPONSE , BUT IT'S STILL THE SAME ! https://www.dropbox.com/s/jyiblizu44v3blc/CapUJKUKture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Thank you!
Can you please share your image here? instead of dropbox

Comment: hi how can  I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I notice it now, you have limited permissions to upload a file here;

Comment: Can you please upload it to public domain, so that, I can view it without any account?

Comment: ok Hope this work https://ibb.co/fTuTqQ

Comment: Try to change the theme, I guess

Comment: yeah and maybe I should go to this choice ! and by away thank you for your patience and attention bro

Comment: You are welcome ! Have a nice time! Please mark the answer as a correct answer and mark it as useful

Comment: Did it resolved for you?